# List of default ubuntu 18.04 gnome shell extensions

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

After installing the `gnome-tweak` extension my left Super key did not work anymore (to raise the activities window).

To try and fix the problem I uninstalled the the tweak tool with `sudo apt-get remove gnome-tweak-tool`, but that did not fix the problem. I then mistakenly uninstalled all the extensions using `sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell-*`. My bad.

Upon restart I was greeted with a terminal window, no login screen. Thus I had to install the gdm3 extension, `supo apt-get install gdm3`, to get a login screen and desktop. Now the menu bar on the left is still missing.

To avoid a reinstall/repair I would simply like to install all the default extensions which come with the ubuntu 18.04 LTS package. Where can I find the list of all these default extensions? I have searched far and wide and could not find it (not even on the [help website](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/index.html)).

EDIT: There was an answer provided, but quickly deleted, suggesting I install the gnome desktop again - `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`. After doing so everything seems to be back to normal. I am not sure if all the default extensions are installed though.

Comment: if you have done `sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell-*`, so you can do `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-*`; you will get more package than you removed, but you will see which ones aren't useful for you and repair your mistake

Comment: just to list all the package that will be install by this command, don't forget to copy the list inside a gedit file or open an other terminal and enter `n` when he will ask you to confirm installation

Comment: I will try this as a last resort, thanks. My problem is I will end up where I started - with extensions that may potentially cause the problem again - without me knowing which one it is. I do note that the left Super key is still not working, only the right one. The left is assigned to Meta L (the two swapped for some reason).

Comment: `gnome-tweak-tools` probably mess a little your key assignement, but you can also reassigned the right behavior of those keys really simply (just need to find the good section)

Comment: Doesn't `apt` have a history/log you can check to see what was uninstalled?